# How to say certain things logically?

Tags: logic

I am practicing discrete math and trying to translate certain sentences to logical language. I don't think I exactly understood the translation process. I cannot find a way to translate intermediate questions. Here is the problem that I am stuck on:

```
Let Chef (x) be “x is a chef”, 
Customer(x) be “x is a customer”, 
Meal(x) be “x is a meal”,   
Knows(x, y) be ”x knows y”, 
Cooks(x, y) be “Chef x can cook meal y”, 
Eats(x, y) be “Customer x can eat meal y”.

Only customers can eat meals.
Not all chefs can cook every meal.
There are some customers who can eat every meal cooked by a certain chef.
Every chef knows a chef who can cook the meals he/she cannot cook.
```

Could you mind helping me with this, please? Thank you in advance.

Example: For all x; if x is a cat, then there exist a y such that y is a dog and x, y are friends translates into ∀x(Cat(x) → ∃y(Dog(y) ∧ F riends(x, y))).

Comment: Could you give move context with an example of what precisely they're looking for?

Comment: Do you know which key words translate to which logical connectives, e.g. "every" corresponds to $\forall $?Also, somtimes it helps to consider the converse of each statement, e.g. "only customers can eat meals" is logically equivalent to "non-customers cannot eat meals".

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek I edited the question and added an example.

Comment: Keep in mind that translation isn't just converting words -- just like the natural language case you have to understand the *meaning* of what's written in the source language, and then write something in the target language that also has the same *meaning*. This is further obscured by the fact there are generally two relevant dialects of English: the one people normally speak in, and the one people speak when they're trying to express logical notions.